# Laravel 5.1 - Create user using Socialite and set confirmed column to 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I've got socialite working really well in my Laravel app. I do however have one small issue.

By default, all accounts have a `confirmed` column that is set to `0`, as some users are using social profiles, I would like to set their `confirmed` column to `1` instantly after successful integration with their social profile.

This is my column code from my migration:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(0);
    $table->string('confirmation_code')->nullable();
});
```

And this is my create code inside my socialite auth controller:

```
$new_user = User::create([
    'name' => $user->name,
    'email' => $user->email,
    'oauth_facebook_id' => $provider === 'facebook' ? $user->id : NULL,
    'oauth_twitter_id' => $provider === 'twitter' ? $user->id : NULL,
    'confirmed' => 1,
    'avatar' => $user->avatar
]);
```

Even though `confirmed` is set to `1`, it still makes the account with a `0`.

Am I missing something?

Andy

Comment: Have you added the `confirmed` field to the `fillable` User model property?

Comment: Nice one @James it always slips my mind to check the `fillable` fields. Sorted now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `confirmed` field into the `fillable` property on your `User` model.